# Unable to define callback for async.forEachOf, express, mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch all databases from mongo, each database has a collection 'meta' that contains details of tasks. I want to send details of all tasks to the client.

Fairly new to node.js hence the hacky code, for the code below this is the response the I get.

```
Here
GET /tasks 304 8.283 ms - -
There [object Object]
GET /favicon.ico 304 1.084 ms - -
```

'Here' is logged before 'There'.
I am unable to define the callback for this.

```
// get list of tasks, basically list of dbs
app.get('/tasks', function (req, res) {
    var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/temp');
    connection.on('open', function() {
    // connection established
        new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
        console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
        // database list stored in result.databases
        var allDatabases = result.databases;
        // iterate and add meta and completion
        var sendData = new Array();
        async.forEachOf(allDatabases, function(value, key, callback) {
            var dbName = value.name;
            console.log(dbName);
            var result;
            if(dbName!='local') {
                var database_name = dbName;
                var tempCon = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/'+database_name);
                var Meta = new mongoose.Schema({
                    originalname    : { type: String, trim: true }
                });
                tempCon.model('meta', Meta).find({ task: { $ne: null } }, function(err, doc) {
                    result = doc[0].toObject();
                    var obj = {
                        "task_hash" : database_name,
                        "task_info" : result
                    };
                    sendData.push(obj);
                    console.log("There "+sendData);
                });
            }
        });
        console.log("Here "+sendData);
        res.send(sendData);    
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried defining callback in the function itself, but gave error.

```
        async.forEachOf(allDatabases, function(value, key, callback() {
                                                                   ^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEachOf(obj, iterator, [callback])` So, try to change code like below

```
                console.log("There "+sendData);
            });
        } // end of "if(dbName!='local')"
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Here "+sendData);
        res.send(sendData);
    });
```

---

If `result.databases` is `Array` then more suitably use `map`

```
app.get('/tasks', function (req, res) {
    var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/temp');
    connection.on('open', function() {
        new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
            console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
            // database list stored in result.databases 
            var dbs = result.databases
                .map(function(db) { return db.name}) // transform to ['db1', 'db2', 'local']
                .filter(function(name) { name != 'local' }); // remove 'local'

            async.map(dbs, function(db, callback) {
                var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/' + db);
                var Meta = new mongoose.Schema({
                    originalname : { type: String, trim: true }
                });
                conn.model('meta', Meta).find({ task: { $ne: null } }, function(err, doc) {
                    // probably we need close temporary conn; I don't work with mongodb
                    // If we don't need to close then we call callback instead function(err, doc) and transfrom if finally-function
                    callback(err, (err) ? null : {
                        "task_hash" : db,
                        "task_info" : doc[0].toObject()
                    });
                }); 
            }, 
            // async finally function 
            function(err, results) {
                if (err)
                    return ...; // Show error to user

                console.log(results);
                res.json(results);
            }); // end of async  
        });
    }); // end of connection.on('open', ...
});
```

Comment: Supreme, thanks. Just one edit you will have to add the missing return in the filter
                .filter(function(name) { return name != 'local' }); // remove 'local'

Comment: I had tried this but this part was unreachable, nothing was logged,    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Here "+sendData);
        res.send(sendData);
    }); Why would it be? So that I do not repeat

Comment: Yeah, `function(err) {` is unreachable because you must call `callback(err)` after `sendData.push(obj);` (I missed it in your code). In `filter` I foggot return because I use ES6, so my code like `.filter((name) => name != 'local')` - it's most shortly.

Comment: In the callback, 

callback(err, (err) ? null : {
                        "task_hash" : db,
                        "task_info" : doc[0].toObject()
                    });

If for some cases I want to skip addition, how can it be done?

Comment: Shortly `callback(err, (err) ? null : (not-smth-case) ? { ... data...} : null)`